# Slimscroll and jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, slimscroll

Im trying to do mix them. use a slimlcroll with jQuery DataTable (no pagination).
So, I found these examples:

[Nice simple use of slimscroll](http://jsfiddle.net/yossico/twem3rno/)

[Nice Table](http://jsfiddle.net/hxkvfs60/1/)

Now I tried to make the content of the table use slim scroll but it just doesnt work :(

what I tried is to put a div serrounding the tbody - and slimscoll that div:

```
<div id="slimtest1">     
<tbody>
    ...
</tbody>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yossico/hxkvfs60/2/

I also try to slim scroll the tbody directly: http://jsfiddle.net/yossico/hxkvfs60/3/

```
<tbody id="slimtest1">
...
</tbody>
```

What I want is to scroll the table body via slimscroll and not with the default scrollbar.
None of this worked - can someone please show me the light?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Updated JSFiddle :- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxkvfs60/6/)

```
   <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       ....
       <tbody id="slimtest1">
          ......
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

CSS

```
thead, tbody { display: block; }

tbody {
   height: 200px;       /* For the demo  */
   overflow-y: auto;    /* Vertical scroll    */
   overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you help me with small Issue - on your updated JSFiddle the headers are misplaced. how it can be fixed?